# cannot read property feed of null nodejs google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

I am trying to get some data from a Google Spreadsheet but something it's not working and I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed' of null
```

This is what I have tried.

```
var GoogleSpreadsheetsParser = require('google-spreadsheets-parser');
var publishedUrl = myPublishURL;
var gss = new GoogleSpreadsheetsParser(publishedUrl, 
 {sheetTitle: 'Sample', hasTitle: true});
 console.log(gss.titles);
```

Obviously it's not a code error, but I can't find a way to solve it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? And yes, the document is public and yes, myPublishURL is the URL

Answer (score 0):

### You request is based on the Google Feed API, which has been deprecated

Hence, your error message. You need to find a workaround, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043402/google-feeds-api-not-working-has-it-been-shutdown).

Specificly for Google Sheets: Currently you can call the feeds URL as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687515/get-rows-having-specific-value-in-google-spreadsheet-feed), but mind that this will also get [deprecated soon](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/data).

**Currently working alternatives are using the [Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) or the [Google Visualization API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64476007/how-to-fetch-specific-row-from-google-sheet-by-using-google-sheet-apisnode-js/64477754#64477754).**